# selecting all attributes when searching for one

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

table: **attributes**

```
+---------------+-------------+
| attribute_id  | name        |
+---------------+-------------+
| 1             | color       |
| 2             | material    |
+---------------+-------------+
```

table: **attribute_values**

```
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| attribute_value_id  | attribute_id    | product_id   | value        |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1                   | 1               | 1            | blue         |
| 2                   | 2               | 1            | metal        |
| 3                   | 1               | 2            | red          |
| 4                   | 2               | 2            | metal        |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

And I have the following query:

```
    SELECT
                p.product_id                AS product_id,
                p.name                      AS product_name,
                v.value                     AS attribute_value,
                a.attribute_id              AS attribute_id,
                a.attribute_category_id     AS attribute_category_id,
                a.name                      AS attribute_name,
                c.name                      AS attributes_category_name
    FROM
                products p
    LEFT JOIN
                attribute_values v USING (product_id)
    LEFT JOIN
                attributes a USING (attribute_id)
    LEFT JOIN
                attribute_categories c USING (attribute_category_id)
    WHERE
                (a.name = 'color' AND v.value = 'red')
```

The problem with the query is: I need ALL the attributes when a product matches the WHERE-clausule.

So, what I **get** is this: I get only the 'color'-attribute, but as you can see, the specific product also has a 'material'-attibute.

So when I search for a product with the color red, I also want the OTHER attributes for that specific product (material = metal).

Comment: Move the two conditions to their respective JOINs

Comment: I think I have found the solution, I'll post it as an answer. can you check it please?

Comment: i believe your where criteria doesnt match what you want to accomplish. you might want to split where into joins where they belong

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz: exactly. Check my answer, I think it's correct.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking to quick, I should have tried a little more before posting it.

Comment: Why not just move the conditions, as suggested !?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea - reduced to its essence...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT product_id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_id = 1 THEN value END) color
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_id = 2 THEN value END) material 
         FROM attribute_values 
        GROUP 
           BY product_id
     ) x
 WHERE color = 'red';
```

Oh, and note that `attribute_value_id` appears to serve no purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer:

```
    SELECT
                p.product_id                AS product_id,
                p.name                      AS product_name,
                v.value                     AS attribute_value,
                a.attribute_id              AS attribute_id,
                a.attribute_category_id     AS attribute_category_id,
                a.name                      AS attribute_name,
                c.name                      AS attributes_category_name
    FROM
                products p
    LEFT JOIN
                attribute_values v USING (product_id)
    LEFT JOIN
                attributes a USING (attribute_id)
    LEFT JOIN
                attribute_categories c USING (attribute_category_id)
    WHERE
                p.product_id IN (SELECT p.product_id FROM products p LEFT JOIN attribute_values v USING (product_id) LEFT JOIN attributes a USING (attribute_id) WHERE a.name = 'color' AND v.value = 'red')
```